# Нужно сделать рамку на CSS

Tags: css, css3, веб-дизайн

Всем привет) помогите реализовать [данную рамку](http://pwnz22.ru/ladder/images/brd.png) в CSS. Цвет тени `#ff9933`

`background: rgba(0,0,0,0.88);` а если такой background?) Чтобы смотрелся как [тут](https://i.gyazo.com/629496c756dbcf4024c84940c3a129dd.png)?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px dotted black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933, 
                      inset 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933,       
                   inset 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933, 
              inset 0px 0px 6px 0px #ff9933;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Еще более достоверный вариант, с использованием псевдоэлемента :after http://jsfiddle.net/1c211bg3/

Comment: Вы можете добавить его отдельным ответом

Comment: @VitaliyShevchenko, а чем он лучше?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="block" style: "width: 400px; height: 150px; border: 2px dotted #000; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff9933; border-radius: 3px;">
```